# When using NPOI which files should I add to Visual Studio in C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have been trying to import everything from NPOI but it won´t let me use the library afterwards, so I´m thinking I´m importing the wrong things so if anyone knows that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio to install the library into your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Brian in comment to your question. Best way to include all library related to NPOI is NUGet Package Manager.  Once it is successfully installed all needed library will appear in reference section of your current project.
Then include the NPOI into your file like

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel
```