# Excel Parsing using NuGet NPOI using ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, azure, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using visual studio 2017 most updated version and Asp.Net Core 2.0 SDK to create a Web Api that needs to read excel which was uploaded earlier into Azure File Storage. Now I am able to get the excel file downloaded but I need to read and parse individual cells from the excel sheet. To achieve this currently I am trying to use Package manager NPOI (Nuget).

Below is the command I am using for this:

```
Pm> Install-Package NPOI -Version 2.3.0
```

But after running this I get the below error:

```
Unable to find Package from NuGet
```

Note, I have checked  in my "Project.csproj" file for adding appropriate refernce of , but even after adding it’s not working..

Below is my Project.csproj file:

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`
`<PropertyGroup>`
 
   `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`
 `</PropertyGroup>`

`<ItemGroup>`
   `<Folder Include="Services\" />`
   `<Folder Include="wwwroot\" />`
 `</ItemGroup>`

`<ItemGroup>`
   `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />`
   `<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />`
   `<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.NPOI" Version="2.3.0" />`
 `</ItemGroup>`

`<ItemGroup>`
   `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />`
 `</ItemGroup>`

`</Project>`

....
**Appreciate quick response!**

Comment: Hi I am trying to convert an application from .Net framework 4.6.1 to .Net Core. In .Net 4.6.1, using OleDBAdapter class in System.Data.OleDb namespace to read and write to excel files and read data from individual column cells. But when research around to do the same in .Net Core that library is no more available. How can I do the same in .Net Core ?

Answer (score 3):

NPOI 2.4 supports .NET core 2.0 now. Please update your NPOI package from nuget.

Comment: Does it work with Core 2.2? I just get a warning sign when I install it in my 2.2 core project but it won't tell me what the warning is not will it let me import any of the packages in.

Comment: Yes. We use NPOI 2.4.1 in .NET core 2.2 for some moments

Answer (score 2):

You  can try adding [DOTNETCore.NPOI][Nuget Package], if you are working with .NET 2.0 Core App.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Dotnetcore.NPOI is a migrated .NET core version of NPOI 2.2.1, which was released in 2016. It's too old and no bug fix at all

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to install it through NUGET package manager. 
Go to VS IDE->Tools->NuGet Package Manager-> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

Search NPOI online and install it for your project.
[image]

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286771/when-using-npoi-which-files-should-i-add-to-visual-studio-in-c-sharp/45019882#45019882) link too

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I check [NPOI 2.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/2.3.0) with my Net Core 2.0 Web API application. I found I could install this package successfully, but I got the following warning:

[image]

Then I read a .xlsx file and got the following error:

[image]

Then I manually installed the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) package, but got the new error as follows:

[image]

Per my understanding, we could manually install [SharpZipLib 1.0.0-alpha2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/1.0.0-alpha2) which may compatible with NetCore 2.0, but the NPOI may not fully compatible with your NetCore application. I have tested the same method for reading .xlsx file via NPOI under my .Net Framework project and it could work as expected. I would recommend you could use [ExcelDataReader 3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/3.2.0) or [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.1.0) instead of NPOI.